# convert AudioContext output to mp3 or ogg

Tags: javascript, html, audiocontext

I use AudioContext HTML5 to record audio from microphone and the output  (each frame) is like this :

```
-0.000457763671875,-0.0003662109375,-0.00018310546875,0,0.000152587890625,0.000244140625,0.000244140625,0.000091552734375....
```

what is these numbers and how I can convert it to mp3 or ogg ?

Comment: It might help to include a little code here, also I have done pretty much the same thing using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` on codepen (see [here](https://codepen.io/TheOnlyRealMe/pen/gOMpJaY?editors=0010) and [here](https://codepen.io/TheOnlyRealMe/pen/OJXMVYN?editors=0010)). I think if your looking to download the recording, or using it like a file you would want to be working with blobs [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).